# Printing a numbered outline of a hierarchical tree

Tags: python-3.x, blender

I'm trying to write a function that prints a object hierarchy tree (in Blender 3D but this is a general Python question) with decimal outline numbering.

I require:

- an optional indent with any symbol like `"+"` or `"--"` or no indent `""`, and
- an optionally appended `".0"` to nodes that have children to distinguish branches from leaves.

For example, in Blender I created an armature with bones and hierarchy is like this:

```
+ Life
++ Bacteria
++ Eukaryota
+++ plants
+++ animals
++++ Vertebrates
+++++ amphibians
+++++ reptiles
+++++ mammals
```

In de Text Editor I created this basic script:

```
import bpy
D = bpy.data
root = D.armatures['Armature'].bones['Life']

def print_hierarchy(obj, indent = "+"):
    print(indent, obj.name)
    for child in obj.children:
        print_hierarchy(child, indent+"+")
print_hierarchy(root)
```

this script outputs:

```
+ Life
++ Bacteria
++ Eukaryota
+++ plants
+++ animals
++++ Vertebrates
+++++ amphibians
+++++ reptiles
+++++ mammals
```

I want it to look like this

```
1.0 Life
    1.1 Bacteria
    1.2.0 Eukaryota
        1.2.1 plants
        1.2.2.0 animals
            1.2.2.1.0 Vertebrates
                1.2.2.1.1 amphibians
                1.2.2.1.2 reptiles
                1.2.2.1.3 mammals
```

I've tinkered with the (recursive) function `print_hierarchy()` but it breaks everytime I try to add something new to it. I can't wrap my brain around it so I'd like some help please.

Is a while-loop better / more efficient / faster than a recursive function for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to do e.g.

```
1 Life
    1.1 Bacteria
    1.2 Eukaryota
        1.2.1 plants
        1.2.2 animals
              1.2.2.1 Vertebrates
              1.2.2.1.1 amphibians
              1.2.2.1.2 reptiles
              1.2.2.1.3 mammals
```

As then you don't have to check explicitly whether the node has children to `print` it out. A couple of useful bits of code:

```
for index, child in enumerate(obj.children, 1):
```

This will number each of the `children`, using one-based indices.

```
''.join(('\t', indent, '.', str(index)))
```

Adds a new tab to the start of the previous `indent`, and the `index` to the end. Putting that together:

```
def print_hierarchy(root, indent="1"):
    print('\t'.join([indent, root.name]))
    for index, child in enumerate(root.children, 1):
        print_hierarchy(child, ''.join(('\t', indent, '.', str(index))))
```

I get:

```
1   life
    1.1 bacteria
    1.2 eukaryota
        1.2.1   plants
        1.2.2   animals
            1.2.2.1 vertebrates
                1.2.2.1.1   amphibians
                1.2.2.1.2   reptiles
                1.2.2.1.3   mammals
```

For fuller functionality, it gets more complex:

```
def print_hierarchy(root, indent=None, dec=None, zeroes=False):
    if indent is None:
        indent = []
    elif isinstance(indent, str):
        indent = [indent]
    if dec is None:
        dec = []
        zeroes = False
    elif isinstance(dec, int):
        dec = [str(dec)]
    elif isinstance(dec, str):
        dec = [dec]
    print(' '.join([''.join(indent), 
                    '.'.join(dec + ["0"] if root.children and zeroes else dec), 
                    root.name]))
    for index, child in enumerate(root.children, 1):
        print_hierarchy(child, 
                        indent + [indent[0]] if indent else indent, 
                        dec + [str(index)] if dec else dec,
                        zeroes)

print_hierarchy(root, "\t", 1, True)
```

Comment: You can use `enumerate(seq, 1)` to make the index start at `1` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your recursive function like this:

```
>>> def print_hierarchy(obj, prefix = ''):
        print('{}{} {}'.format(prefix, '.0' if obj.children else '', obj.name))
        for num, child in enumerate(obj.children, 1):
            print_hierarchy(child, '    {}.{}'.format(prefix, num))

>>> print_hierarchy(root, '1')
1.0 Life
    1.1 Bacteria
    1.2.0 Eukaryota
        1.2.1 plants
        1.2.2.0 animals
            1.2.2.1.0 Vertebratens
                1.2.2.1.1 amphibians
                1.2.2.1.2 reptiles
                1.2.2.1.3 mammals
```

But I’d agree with jonrsharpe, that the numbering does not really make sense for a hierarchy. It makes it seem that `Life` and `Bacteria` are on the same level, but `Eukaryota` isn’t.